# Windows phone 7: post some values, retrieve the response

Tags: windows-phone-7, post, data-retrieval

How can I post a value to an online page, and then retrieve the response to put it in a string?
It's a PHP page that take the `$_POST` value and then echo a response that I want to grab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.NET.HTTPWEBREQUEST%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22SILVERLIGHT,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) object.

```
public void DoWork()
{
    var url = "http://posttestserver.com/post.php";
    // Create the web request object
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    // Start the request
    webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);    
}
void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    // End the stream request operation
    Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
    // Create the post data
    // Demo POST data 
    string postData = "Username=MyUserName&password=MyPassword";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    // Add the post data to the web request
    postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    postStream.Close();
    // Start the web request
    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);
}

void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response;
        // End the get response operation
        response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        var Response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        streamResponse.Close();
        streamReader.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        // Error treatment
        // ...
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoWork();
}
```

his code adapted slightly from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952094/wp7-windows-phone-7-httpwebrequest-losing-post-data)

Comment: ok, i think it works. but where i can retrieve my response? if i use:
                var Response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(Response.ToString());
i get an error

Comment: streamReader.ReadToEnd() already returns a string so .ToString() is redundant.  Assuming you are creating a MessageBox within the GetResponseCallback() method, be aware that you are on a new thread there, so to pop up the messagebox, you need to call it as `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(Response));`

Comment: Yes, you're right! :-P
but now, last question to understand this thing, how can i attach a field value to the post data? i have done this but i get an error:

string postData = "language=en&value=" + testo.Text;

Comment: how can i put a textBox value in the post strings??? i retrieve an error of invalid cross thread

Comment: You could either store the value in a string before you call the background thread (easy way) or use the dispatcher to get the value within the method.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710034/how-to-read-textbox-text-value-from-another-thread-in-wpf for examples.  Sorry I can't give you code directly as I am on vacation now. :)

Comment: Maybe mark this answer as accepted and ask again in a new question. As I say, I am on vacation so can't give you an answer, but starting a new question for this additional information would get you more answers.